# How do I add a space every three characters in a form in JavaScript and have a replace function?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, character, space

How do I add a space every three characters in a form in JavaScript and have a replace function? I've seen the question, but I'm still unclear and new at this and I'm not sure where the code would go into the script. This is what I have so far. Please be specific.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function var myfunction()
    {
    }

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <FORM ACTION="rules.html" NAME="form">
    <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="inp" SIZE=40 onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace('t','A').replace('a','U')">
    </FORM>

    </script>
```

Comment: *"Please be specific"*? Does anyone else see the dripping irony in that?

Comment: and you're trying to do... what ?

Comment: It would've been great for you to read the title... or even just politely point out that it wasn't in the description...

Comment: So did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your trying to enter in RNA and have it automatically split out into triplets on entry.  But even if that's not what you're doing, this should get you what you need.

First, remove the extra closing `</script>` tag you have below your form.

Then, replace the `input` in your form with the following:

```
<input type="text" name="inp" size="40" onkeyup="this.value=myfunction(this.value);">
```

and in the `myfunction` function use this:

```
function myfunction(val) {
    val = val.replace('t','A').replace('a','U');
    val = val.replace(/(\w{3})$/, '$1 ');
    return val;
}
```

Granted this could all be cleaner if you pulled your javascript out of your markup and cleaned up your HTML a little, but this should get you going.